# Time based fields on CaseMilestone not showing any value

Tags: case, servicecloud, entitlements

We have Entitlements and Milestones configured in our org and as standard functionality, Salesforce provides **elapsed** and **stopped** time in minutes, hours, and days format when a Case is on-hold (`isStopped` set to true). The Milestone get paused but the fields are not showing any value. See below

[image]

---

I thought there might be something wrong with the layout or FLS, so I SOQL the same and found nothing.

[image]

---

On the [EntityMilestone](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_entitymilestone.htm) object reference document, following steps have been followed:

> **StoppedTimeInDays**
>
> To display this field, select Enable stopped time and actual elapsed
>   time on the Entitlement Settings page and add the field to the object
>   milestone page layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the milestone is stopped upon using `isStopped` attribute at Case level then after certain time when it comes back to isStopped=false then automatically those StoppedTimeInX, ElapsedTimeInX and ActualElapsedTimeInX values are not displayed.

> **Those values only get displayed when Milestone is completed.**

Refer this screenshot below from my DE where all the respective values are displaying.

[image: Milestone]

Comment: if you look at the soql, it is querying case milestone object. Besides, the reference in my question also mentions that I need to have those fields on object milestone page layout, which is case milestone in my case.

Comment: Are you telling that the elapsed time and stoped time fields are gonna be calculated for work orders not cases? I didn’t find any reference if the same in documentation. Can you please put some more light on this?

Comment: Refer my updated answer and experiment

Comment: thanks man. You saved my day with Salesforce support, as I had opened a case with them and was very dubious about getting a proper answer from there. :D

Comment: In future, for any type of questions, post in SFSE and copy that link to twitter and tag #askforce to get prompt response