# Milestone elapsed / actual elapsed / stopped times are always empty

Tags: entitlements, casemilestone

I have a `CompletedCaseMilestone` custom object that I use to store the completed milestones for statistical analysis later. Everything is working great, but I came across an issue when I'm also using `IsStopped` flag on the `Case` object.

I have a process that sets `IsStopped` to `true` if the status is `On Hold`, and set it to `false` otherwise. The flag is working - when it is `true`, the milestones are stopped, when it changes back to `false`, the milestones continue to count.

The issue is that the `StoppedTimeInX`, `ElapsedTimeInX` and `ActualElapsedTimeInX` fields are always empty. I need those fields in order to calculate the actual time for the milestone to complete without the stopped time.

I've enabled `Enable stopped time and actual elapsed time` checkbox in the `Entitlement Settings` section, and added all the fields to the `Case Milestone` page layout - but still nothing.

How can I get those fields to work?

**Update:**

I've confirmed in the work bench that the fields in question exist on the `CaseMilestone` object.

[image]

Comment: Did you check this answer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/236867/time-based-fields-on-casemilestone-not-showing-any-value

Comment: @SantanuBoral I did, but the answer is not accurate - once the `Enable stopped time and actual elapsed time` flag in `Entitlement Settings` is on, the fields do exist on `CaseMilestone`. See updated question.

Comment: Refer my updated answer and let me know if it solves the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the milestone is stopped upon using `isStopped` attribute at Case level then after certain time when it comes back to `isStopped=false` then automatically those `StoppedTimeInX`, `ElapsedTimeInX` and `ActualElapsedTimeInX` values are not displayed.

**Those values only get displayed when Milestone is completed**.

Refer this screenshot below from my DE where all the respective values are displaying.

[image: Milestone]

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason I cannot get this result. When a milestone is complete, it simply disappears from the list of milestone :/ The documentation for this feature is just so bad that I cannot find any information about those issues...

Comment: If the milestone disappears from the list then that a separate issue. You can post a separate question on that